# get all rows if there is only few row match in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following two tables:

Table 1:

```
student_id    Name
...................
1             Kumar
2             kishan
3             Mohan
4             Kanha
5             Murat
```

Table 2:

```
student_id      is_attend
.........................
1               1
4               1
```

Table 2 represents the students who have an attended status.
The following is the result we would like to get. So that we can show through `PHP` the attendance of each student.

Result:

```
student_id      is_attend
..........................
1               1
2               0
3               0
4               1
```

Comment: Man, people should just start to have the relevant data in the same tables. Using join at all will start to use up large query spaces when your tables start to get bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select T1.student_id,T2.is_attend from 
          table1 T1 left join 
          table2 T2 on 
          T1.student_id=T2.student_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Left join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) as below :

```
Select Table1.*,Table2.is_attend
from Table1
left join Table2
on Table1.student_id = Table2.student_id
```

Comment: you can add the IFNULL(Table2.is_attend,0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub-query also :

```
select s.student_id,
         (select IFNULL(is_attend,0) from attend where student_id=s.student_id) as is_attend 
    from student as s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT      t1.student_id,
            t1.Name,
            IFNULL(t2.is_attend,0)
FROM        Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN   Table2 t2 ON t1.student_id = t2.student_id
```

You can see this here  -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86511/2

Hope this helps!!!